ShopifySharp encoding
I have some encoding problems and I don't know how to fix them.
For example when I try to set this title to a product using ShopifySharp Nuget:
shopifyProduct.Title = "Spiral flute 40°"
That's what I see in Shopify: Spiral flute 40&#176
I also have this problem with special characters specific to some languages.
Any idea how to fix that?
Version: 6.19.0
